# Clustered indexes and covered queries

Tags: t-sql

I have a table that has data by year, state, and county. The county identifier is stored as a FIPS code that codes both the state and the county.

I've created a CLUSTERED INDEX on year and county, and I understand that the data will be physically stored in that arrangement.

**Questions**:

- Since data are stored by FIPS code, are they automatically arranged in order of state?
- It seems to me that adding a non-clustered index on State would not gain me anything. Is this true?
- More generally, if i have a clustered index on several variables, are queries that have WHERE, GROUP BY, or ORDER BY clauses on components of the index "covered", and therefore don't need indexes?

Answer (score 0):

A query has no way of knowing that state happens to be in order in absence of an index on state.
A query on state will not use the composite index on year and fips.

State will benefit from an index.
You could have a separate index on state.
Or include state in the composite index - year, state, FIPS.

Say you have a composite index col1, col2, col3. And the Where is on col3.  Query can use the composite index but it will be a scan.  If you have a lot or critical queries that use col3 then place an index on col3 and see if you get a benefit.  And you need to test loaded with data.  The other factor is if the composite index is used a lot then it might already be in memory.